# java basic: the Template can only accept one dimension change why?

Tags: java, c++, templates

I declare the private variable as

```
private List<MultipartFile> files;
```

When I want initialize it I do in this way:

```
files=new ArrayList<CommonsMultipartFile>();
```

you can see the CommonsMultipartFile extends the MultipartFile Interface
The compile give me error as:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<CommonsMultipartFile> to List<MultipartFile>
```

Anyone who know the reason? 
If I really want to Stable the collection and inside class type, how can I do it? 
Can I do similar staff in C++?

Comment: Asking if there is a C++ equivalent should be a separate question. Keeping in mind that you should wait until you have an answer to your first question: you need correct code before asking for an equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If im not mistaken, in java generics :

If you have two class `A`, class `B extends A` and a generic `class Generic<T>`, then `Generic<B>` does not extends `Generic<A>`. That's why your cast does not work.

You could declare `files` as :

```
private List<? extends MultipartFiles> files;
```

With this, you should be able to do your assignment.

Edit : As it's said in other response, this declaration would prevent to add other things than `null`. Limited interest indeed...

Comment: Official tutorial talking about wildcards: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

Comment: You are correct, but the resultant field wouldn't be very useful. It might be what the OP wants, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 4):

Inheritance principle doesn't apply with type parameter.

```
List<MultipartFile> files=new ArrayList<MultipartFile>();
```

=> Perfectly valid.

```
List<MultipartFile> files=new ArrayList<CommonsMultipartFile>();
```

=> Perfectly wrong.

**Why doesn't compiler let do this?**

Assuming you create an `ArrayList<CommonsMultipartFile>`, you would expect to have ONLY `CommonsMultipartFile` elements. No surprise until there.

If compiler lets you assign this `ArrayList` to a `List<MultipartFile>` as reference type, there's nothing to prevent you from populating your `ArrayList` with some objects extending `MultipartFile` and even different from `CommonsMultipartFile` !

The problem is that you initially expected to have ONLY `CommonsMultipartFile` elements.

So java syntax doesn't let such a surprise appears...

Furthermore, doing this `private List<? extends MultipartFiles> files` works **but logically prevents you from ADDING some objects into it from the same reason I explained !** Caution to that since it is often misunderstood.

Instead of `? extends` wildcard, you'll want to prefer doing `private List<? super CommonsMultipartFile>` if you want to add `CommonsMultipartFile` objects within it afterwards using this reference type.

Anyway, as you're assigning solely an `ArrayList` with `CommonMultipartFile` objects and so no objects higher in the hierarchy, the most appropriate syntax in this case is:

```
List<MultipartFile> files=new ArrayList<MultipartFile>();
```

Comment: Good points all, but I suspect the OP is just being overzealous in applying the advice to use interface types wherever possible. I suspect he wants to both add and get items from the list and therefore it should be List<CommonsMultipartFile>

Comment: Oh, and "wildcard" has a very specific meaning in Java generics. It is when a type parameter contains the ? character. MultipartFile in List<MultipartFile> is just a type paramater. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: @John Watts Exactly, for his use, the simplest way to add and get is to write: List<MultipartFile> files = new ArrayList<MultipartFile>();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use the list with any subtype of MultipartFile, make both generic parameters MultipartFile. If you only want to use it with CommonsMultipartFile, make both parameters CommonsMultipartFile. And in the unlikely case that you never put anything into this list through this reference, you could instead make it:

```
List<? extends MultipartFile> files = ...
```

You could get items from the list and they would always be a subtype of MultipartFile but you could only add null.